# Function of a linked list

Tags: java, function, linked-list, nodes

I've got the following assignment in preparation for a lab. I've genuinely tried to understand, but it doesn't make sense to me.

The question goes like "**Which of the given solutions is the correct output after executing the fun method on the linked list defined below. Note, we pass the first element of linked list defined below as a parameter to func - the first element also happens to be called 'first'.**"

```
Client code:
var input = first -> r -> e -> d -> i -> v -> i -> d -> e -> r -> null; 
public Node fun(Node x) {
   Node first = x;
   Node magic = null;
   while (first != null) {
      Node second = first.next;
      first.next  = magic; 
      magic       = first;
      first       = second;
   }
   return magic;
}
```

So what I gathered is that you call on the function with each of the nodes in the linked list, one at a time. So first fun(first), then fun(r) etc.

I've got four answer alternatives:

```
first -> v -> i -> r -> e -> d -> null

first -> r -> e -> d -> i -> v -> i -> d -> e -> r -> null

first -> d -> r -> v -> r -> d -> null

first -> d-> e -> r -> i -> v -> i -> r -> e -> d -> null
```

So the question is, what does the function do with the linked list? Does it delete nodes, interchange nodes or both?

Comment: "_So what I gathered is that you call on the function with each of the nodes_". **No!** Your exercise explicitly states "_Note, we pass the first element of linked list defined below as a parameter to func_". The only method call is `fun(first)`. Simply walk through the pseudocode by hand.

Answer (score 1):

Think in terms of invariants. What's the invariant of the loop? `first` is a current node, while `magic` is a node "left" to it. In each step you are setting `next` of the current node to point on `magic`. 
Even better invariant is that `magic` is a head of the reversed part of the original list up to the current (`first`) node.
Then you can realize that this function reverses the list and returns head of the new list. So the answer would be: `r -> e -> d -> i -> v -> i -> d -> e -> r -> first -> null`.